# No contrast on meta between visited and unvisited links (new behavior)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On meta I am seeing no difference in color between visited and unvisited links, either titles on the main page or other links on individual pages.  In the following screen shot, I have visited the second question but not the first:

[image: question titles]

In the following screen shot, I have visited my profile but not Stéphane's, nor have I visited the MSO post in this browser (I posted that comment from elsewhere):

[image: question page]

These links used to be visibly different.  I believe the change happened within the last 24-36 hours.

I turned off Stylish to verify that no custom CSS is causing this; no change.  Main looks fine.

MacOS 10.6, Firefox 27.0.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I increased the color difference between visited and unvisited links, the change will occurs after the next production build.

Comment: Thanks!  The contrast in the titles on the main page is now much better (I can see a difference).  I'm still not seeing a difference in the blue links on individual pages, but that's far less important to me.